# How do you access the Access/PeopleHR API?

Tags: rest, postman

In order to cancel my account I needed to export my data manually as they don't have a formal/GDPR compliant bulk download process during cancellation.

Is there a postman collection available as a sample?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the API is here:

https://apidocs.peoplehr.com/

You need to create an API key using this guide, but in trying to do so you may be informed that you need to pay for access (just tell the account manager you are leaving and they will give you access):

https://help.peoplehr.com/en/articles/1970068-creating-an-api-key

In order to get data from the RESTful API, I created a sample (not extensive) Postman collection

https://www.getpostman.com/collections/8eb164b8101d8b97db6e

You will need to create 2 environment variables:

- Server (just use this for live: https://api.peoplehr.net)
- APIKey (get this from your Settings section)

They do have a bulk download feature available via the Plugins > New Request section of your account, but it only exports previously created Queries, which might be all you need. There is a Windows app that can run these too. More info here:

https://help.peoplehr.com/en/articles/1020240-offline-backup-tool